# How to find connections on board? - DIY Keyboard from Old Laptop

Tags: pcb, usb, pinout, diy, keyboard

I have a project that I have hit a wall on. I need your guidance!

[image: Photo of Board]
I need to find the spots on the board for the 4 USB connections. 
The attached photo is of the board. 
There are 4 connections I need to find are: 5v+, data -, data +, ground
It came out of an Apple MacBook Pro early 2008 A126C w/ bad mother board.

I've found instructions online for the models newer and older than mine on how to solder a USB cable to the controller board to use the keyboard and trackpad. I can't find anyone who has figured out the connections on mine. Can anyone help? I don't even know where to start... Is this even possible to do?  I have searched the other topics but none had suggestions on how to find the connections.

Any thoughts or insight is welcome at this point!

Thanks!!!

Comment: Look at the chips datashits and trace traces

Comment: This may be one of those times where the situation is unique enough that a select few may know what you are talking about.  For the rest of us, what is the overall goal here?  FYI, unless Apples are very different, most laptops connect the keyboard to the mother board as a grid of switches.  Not using USB.

Comment: @st2000 Apple has used usb for keyboards and track pads for decades now. And so have most others. The major laptop brands do not use direct matrix connections. Keyboards and track pads were ps2 and now usb. Same for cameras and internal bluetooth, SD card readers, thumbprint readers,  etc. Get with the times.

Comment: Not arguing.  Just want to know.  If the keyboard is usb... then what's that ~30 pin ribbon connector in the image in the OP's question?

Comment: @st2000 connection to the keyboard membrane itself I assume. This board will register the keypad button presses and transfer them to the PC via a USB-HID keyboard protocol. Some laptops have the control ICs on the motherboard, others will have them on the keyboard, it just depends on how the laptop was designed to fit together - half the time laptops will have several smaller PCBs dotted around with random combinations of stuff - like a DC jack and a USB port, or a touchpad controller and LED indicators. It's just however they fit everything into the small space.

Comment: @st2000 let me rephrase, laptops rarely have a direct membrane matrix control interface. The controller tends to be usb to the motherboard. The membrane is still used, just not directly.

Comment: @Passerby you're very incorrect. The majority of laptops connect the keyboard membrane directly to the EC (embedded controller), even to this day, and the majority of touchpads still uses PS/2 (also connected to the EC). The EC is always located on the motherboard (never on a daughter board) and, in turn, connects to the chipset, usually through the LPC bus. USB is rarely used in keyboard&mouse connections, unless it's something very specific like Apple - usually, you'll find USB used internally for connecting things like webcam, fingerprint reader, SD reader, Bluetooth (sometimes mPCIe/M2).

Comment: Sure, let me go tell Apple, Dell, and Lenovo they are doing it wrong @АрсенийПичугин

Comment: @passerby I have a box of mobos next to me and they all connect the keyboard to the EC. Picked a random one, Latitude D410 motherboard, schematics are first hit on Google for "Dell D410 schematic", the keyboard is connected to EC. Another one, Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E420s, sch available, keyboard connected to EC. Apple seems to be an exception - they seem to use I2C a lot last 4-5yrs, but they did use USB *at some point*. Went through some other motherboards(~20), not a single one has a USB chip for keyboard. Seems like your "majority" and "tends to be" claims are bunk. What are they based on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [CY8C24794](http://www.cypress.com/file/140926) has USB D+ on pin 20 and D- on pin 21. Tracks from these pins appear to go to the connector on the lower right. Here we also see a thick trace with a pad marked '5V0' which I am guessing is USB +5V. Ground is probably connected to the grid pattern on the PCB, so should be easy to meter out.

Comment: Ground is pprobably on most ccapacitors

Comment: @Bruce Abbott You are the Man!!!  Thank you so much for answering the question in a way that not only showed me the answer but enabled me to do it on my own next time.  One more question how did you know which of the chips was for USB? Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't 'know', but Cypress Semiconductor are well known for their USB chips. So when I saw that part number I figured it would be the one. Download datasheet, find USB pin numbers for that package, trace where they go, aha!